# Question from P1 probability exam book - conditional probability continuous case

Tags: probability, probability-theory, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions

Let X and Y be continuous random variables with conditional and marginal
p.d.f.’s given by
$$ f_X(x) = \frac{x^3e^{-x}}{6}I_{(0,∞)}(x) $$

and
$$ f_{X|Y} (X|Y) = \frac{3y^2}{x^3} I_{(0,x)}(y) $$

a) Find the joint p.d.f. of X and Y.
b) Find the conditional p.d.f. of X given Y = y.

It seems the book made a mistake of writing $$ f_{X|Y} (X|Y) $$ instead of $$ f_{Y|X} (Y|X) $$ Is this fair to say?

Comment: The joint pdf is $f_X(x)\cdot f_{X|Y}(x|y)$.

Comment: the joint pdf is in fact $$ f_Y(y)*f_{X|Y}(x|y) $$ ... that's what makes this problem confusing because we don't know $$ f_Y(y) $$ . thoughts?

Comment: Then use $f_X(x)\cdot f_{Y|X}(y|x)$. It seems that you have made a typo. I've made an edit.

Comment: @callculus42 unfortunately the edit you made it not what the book said... if I had been given $$ f_{Y|X}(y|x) $$ I would not be asking this question here...

Comment: Maybe, but I've googled it and I've found this [here](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/2-problem-445-let-x-y-continuous-random-variables-conditional-marginal-pdf-s-given-xo-e-fx-q88906420). So I'm pretty sure that this is a typo.

Comment: thank you well that saves a lot of headache...

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a typographical error. The expression
$$\frac{3y^2}{x^3}I_{(0,x)}(y),\tag{$\ast$}$$
viewed as a function of $x$ with $y$ fixed, does not integrate to $1$ (the integral would run from $x=y$ to $x=\infty$), so it cannot be the conditional density of $X$ given $Y=y$. However, viewed as a function of $y$ with $x$ fixed, it integrates to $1$ (the integral would run from $y=0$ to $y=x$). So I would regard $(\ast)$ as $f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)$. You can now determine the joint density $f(x,y)=f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)f_X(x)$.